# Using a secondary constructor in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, constructor, android-adapter, class-constructors

I get the error:

> Expecting member declaration

```
class MyAdapter(val context: Context)  {
    constructor(context: Context,  itemInfos: List<ItemInfo>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentItemViewHolder> {

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
class MyAdapter(val context: Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentItemViewHolder>() {
    constructor(context: Context,  itemInfos: List<ItemInfo>): this(context) {

    }
}
```

If you inherit from another class you should specify it in class declaration, not constructor declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You should put superclass after class declaration:

```
class MyAdapter(val context: Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentItemViewHolder>  {
    constructor(context: Context,  itemInfos: List<ItemInfo>): this(context) {

    }
}
```